# how to make a delay and print it?

Tags: python

anyone can help me. I am working on the traffic light and I want to make a delay for green and red lights and print so I tried this code:

```
   import time
   t=10
   while True:
       time.sleep(1)
       print(t)
       t = t - 1
       if(t==0):
           break
```

but it repeated twice:

```
  10
  9
  8
  7
  6
  5
  4
  3
  2
  1
  10
  9
  8
  7
  6
  5
  4
  3
  2
  1
```

i expected :

```
 10
 9
 8
 7
 6
 5
 4 
 3
 2
 1
 0
```

Comment: please provide a complete example that reproduces your code. In your code you dont even set `t`. I have run your code with setting t as 10 outside the loop and it only runs once not twice

Comment: I have copied and ran your updated code and it only runs once not twice

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put t, but it repeated twice even I tried your code the same result I get.

Comment: The code you have posted only runs once from 10 down to 1, it doesnt repeat

Comment: I rebooted the pc and it fixed, weird. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import time

t = 10
while (t >= 0):
  time.sleep(1)
  print(t)
  t -= 1
```

Comment: This won't print 0, use ```while(t>=0)``` instead

Answer (score 3):

change `if(t ==0):` to `if(t<0):`

if `t==0`, it will print upto 1(ie from 10-1),it stops when t=0.

if want to include 0, then change the to `t<0`.so it prints upto 0(from 10-0), it stops when t value is less than 0.

check out this code:

**code:**

```
import time
t=10
while True:
  time.sleep(1)
  print(t)
  t = t - 1
  if(t < 0):
    break
```

**output:**

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Can you please provide an explanation what's the difference to his code? Why should t < 0 be better than t == 0?

Comment: @RedX that's because 0 is also supposed to be printed.

Comment: how does this solve his actual problem which is the code prints twice? you could have added this `t<0` as a comment

Comment: actually the code doesn't repeats it just prints 10 to 1 @ChrisDoyle.

Comment: exactly thats what i put in the comment i didnt post it as an aswer cause its just that....a comment....the op posted an issue and this answer doesnt solve that issue